# QThread never starts

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I am trying to create a thread that will try to connect to a serial port. In debug mode, none of the signals emitted from within Serial is ever fired. connectToPort() is also never entered.

Am I missing something here?

I am used to subclassing QThread and this is my first attempt at using the moveToThread() method.

Here is the code:

**Bluetooth.cpp:**

```
void Bluetooth::deviceSelected()
{
    QStringList comPort;

    comPort = bluetoothSelectedDevice->split(":");

    qDebug() << comPort.at(0);

    //Create COM port object to be used with QSerialPort by providing COM port in text.
    QSerialPortInfo temp(comPort.at(0));

    if(temp.isBusy())
    {
        qDebug() << "COM port is already open!";
        //TODO: Notify user that COM port is already open and that he should close it and try again.
        return;
    }

    //Create serial port object.
    serialPort = new QSerialPort(temp);

    //Instantiate a serial class object.
    serial = new Serial(serialPort);

    //Create a thread to be used with the serial object.
    serialWorkerThread = new QThread();

    //Move serial object to serial worker thread.
    serial->moveToThread(serialWorkerThread);

    QObject::connect(serialWorkerThread, SIGNAL(started()), serial, SLOT(connectToPort()));
    QObject::connect(serialWorkerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), serialWorkerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QObject::connect(serial, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(on_connected()));
    QObject::connect(serial, SIGNAL(couldNotConnect()), this, SLOT(on_couldNotConnect()));
    QObject::connect(serial, SIGNAL(portSettingsFailed()), this, SLOT(on_portSettingsFailed()));
}
```

**Serial.h:**

```
#ifndef SERIAL_H
#define SERIAL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSerialPort>

class Serial : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Serial(QSerialPort *serialPort);

signals:
    void connected();
    void couldNotConnect();
    void portSettingsFailed();

public slots:
    void connectToPort();

private:
    QSerialPort *serialPort;

};

#endif // SERIAL_H
```

**Serial.cpp:**

```
#include "serial.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QDebug>

Serial::Serial(QSerialPort *serialPort)
{
    this->serialPort = serialPort;
}

void Serial::connectToPort()
{
    //Try to connect 5 times.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(!serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
            qDebug() << "Failed to open port";
            if(i == 4)
            {
                emit couldNotConnect();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Set port settings.
    if(serialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600) &&
       serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8) &&
       serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity) &&
       serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop) &&
       serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl) != true)
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to configure port";
        emit portSettingsFailed();
    }

    emit connected();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you paste all your code? Are you verifying the execution is actually getting to the end of your `deviceSelected` method? It looks like you never start your thread.

i.e. after your connections add:

```
serialWorkerThread->start();
```